# What are the drivers for tapping a bond?

Tags: fixed-income, bond

I believe there are several drivers which bring a government to tap a bond:

- Reduced issuance in that particular bond line
- Liquidity of the bond
- Attractiveness of the bond
- Price above par

Could you please delve deeper into the *price above par* driver and possibly explain why this is a driver, plus any other drivers you can think of?

Comment: If in the official statistics government debt is measured by face value, then by reissuing a bond at price above par, the government receives a lot of revenue (due to the high market price of the bond) while making a relatively small apparent addition to the government debt.